# Connecting to POSTGRES database using DataSet for Simple Report in C#

Tags: c#, postgresql, dataset

I'm using Simple Reports in Visual Studio 2012, c# language, and when I try to connect my data from database using DataSet, I cannot find my postgres database (w/c is 64bit, version 9.3) in creating the connection, using DataSet.

[image]

As you can see, there's no postgres data source...

How do I do this?

Thank you.

Comment: If you don't post your code none can help you.

Answer (score 0):

Wild guess based on insufficient information provided:

Visual Studio 2012 is a 32-bit executable.

You installed the 64-bit PostgreSQL ODBC driver, but not the 32-bit driver.

The ODBC driver must be the same architecture as the *application using the driver*, not the server. So you need the 32-bit ODBC driver installed.

[Download psqlODBC here](http://www.postgresql.org/ftp/odbc/versions/msi/).